# TypeScript const assertions: how to use Array.prototype.includes?

Tags: typescript3.0

I am trying to use an array of elements as union type, something that became easy with const assertions in TS 3.4, so I can do this:

```js
const CAPITAL_LETTERS = ['A', 'B', 'C', ..., 'Z'] as const;
type CapitalLetter = typeof CAPITAL_LETTERS[string];
```

Now I want to test whether a string is a capital letter, but the following fails with "not assignable to parameter of type":

```js
let str: string;
...
CAPITAL_LETTERS.includes(str);
```

Is there any better way to fix this rather than casting `CAPITAL_LETTERS` to `unknown` and then to `Array<string>`?

Comment: I think you want `type CapitalLetter = typeof CAPITAL_LETTERS[number]`... that is, index on `number`, not `string`.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

[The standard library signature for `Array<T>.includes(u)`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.5.2/lib/lib.es2016.array.include.d.ts#L36) assumes that the value to be checked is of the same or narrower type than the array's elements `T`.  But in your case you are doing the opposite, checking against a value which is of a *wider* type.  In fact, the only time you would say that `Array<T>.includes<U>(x: U)` is a mistake and must be prohibited is if there is no overlap between `T` and `U` (i.e., when `T & U` is `never`).

Now, if you're not going to be doing this sort of "opposite" use of `includes()` very often, and you want zero runtime efects, you should just widen `CAPITAL_LETTERS` to `ReadonlyArray<string>` via type assertion:

```
(CAPITAL_LETTERS as ReadonlyArray<string>).includes(str); // okay
```

If, on the other hand, you feel seriously enough that this use of `includes()` should be accepted with no type assertions, and you want it to happen in all of your code, you could [merge in a custom declaration](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html):

```
// global augmentation needed if your code is in a module
// if your code is not in a module, get rid of "declare global":
declare global { 
  interface ReadonlyArray<T> {
    includes<U>(x: U & ((T & U) extends never ? never : unknown)): boolean;
  }
}
```

That will make it so that an array (well, a readonly array, but that's what you have in this example) will allow any parameter for `.includes()` as long as there is some overlap between the array element type and the parameter type.  Since `string & CapitalLetter` is not `never`, it will allow the call.  It will still forbid `CAPITAL_LETTERS.includes(123)`, though.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why the standard definition doesn't allow testing of wider types? Isn't testing a wider type the whole point of .includes with a const-asserted array? If I already know my value is a member of the readonly array (narrower type) then I don't need to call includes which makes the signaure as-is useless doesn't it?

Comment: I think if the array contains literals then yes, it seems crazy to forbid wider types.  But in cases like `string` or `number` where there are a large number of possible values then it's reasonable.  I think it just wasn't an intended use case and the augmentation that would allow it is more complex and might have some edge cases.  It's generally easy to widen the array type when checking with includes.  ‍♂️

Comment: I used `x: (T & U) extends never ? never : U` instead, which seems a bit simpler and more straightforward.

Comment: @jcalz So what is the intended pattern then, to narrow a string type to one of a union of strings type?

Answer (score 14):

Another way to solve it is with a type guard

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards

```js
const myConstArray = ["foo", "bar", "baz"] as const

function myFunc(x: string) {
    //Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '"foo" | "bar" | "baz"'.
    if (myConstArray.includes(x)) {
        //Hey, a string could totally be one of those values! What gives, TS?
    }
}

//get the string union type
type TMyConstArrayValue = typeof myConstArray[number]

//Make a type guard
//Here the "x is TMyConstArrayValue" tells TS that if this fn returns true then x is of that type
function isInMyConstArray(x: string): x is TMyConstArrayValue {
    return myConstArray.includes(x as TMyConstArrayValue)

    //Note the cast here, we're doing something TS things is unsafe but being explicit about it
    //I like to this of type guards as saying to TS:
    //"I promise that if this fn returns true then the variable is of the following type"
}

function myFunc2(x: string) {
    if (isInMyConstArray(x)) {
        //x is now "foo" | "bar" | "baz" as originally intended!
    }
}
```

While you have to introduce another "unnecessary" function this ends up looking clean and working perfectly. In your case you would add

```js
const CAPITAL_LETTERS = ['A', 'B', 'C', ..., 'Z'] as const;
type CapitalLetter = typeof CAPITAL_LETTERS[string];
function isCapitalLetter(x: string): x is CapitalLetter {
    return CAPITAL_LETTERS.includes(x as CapitalLetter)
}

let str: string;
isCapitalLetter(str) //Now you have your comparison

//Not any more verbose than writing .includes inline
if(isCapitalLetter(str)){
  //now str is of type CapitalLetter
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Adding to [@imagio's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62943000/12983861), you can make a generic type guard (thanks to [@wprl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17847/wprl) for simplification)

```js
function isIn<T>(values: readonly T[], x: any): x is T {
    return values.includes(x);
}
```

And use it with any `as const` array:

```js
const specialNumbers = [0, 1, 2, 3] as const;

function foo(n: number) {
     if (isIn(specialNumbers, n)) {
         //TypeScript will say that `s` has type `0 | 1 | 2 | 3` here
     }
}
```

### Explanation

#### Type guards

Functions that return something like `x is T` are known as type guards. TypeScript docs have a great description of what these are [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates)

Essentially, type guards are functions with return type in form `parameterName is Type`, where `parameterName` is name of one of the function parameters. During runtime they actually return a `boolean`

If the function returns `true`, TypeScript will assume that the value passed to parameter `parameterName` has type `T`. We can use this in `true` branches of conditional statements. As an example:

```js
function isString(x: unknown): x is string {
    return typeof x === 'string' 
}

function formatValue(value: number | string): string {
    if (isString(value)) {
        // This code will be executed only if `isString(value)`
        // returned `true`. Since `isString` is a type guard with type
        // `x is string`, and we pass `value` to `x`, TypeScript
        // will know that `value` has type `string` in this branch

        // This is why we can use `.toUpperCase()` here - this
        // methods exists on values of type `string`
        return value.toUpperCase()
    }

    // This code is executed only when `isString(value)` returned
    // `false`. Here, TypeScript will not that `value` is NOT 
    // of type `string`. Since `value` parameter has type 
    // `number | string`, but is surely not `string` in this part of
    // code, than it has to have type `number` here

    // This is why we can use `.toFixed()` here

    // Note that this line would give error, since `.toUpperCase()`
    // does not exist on type `number`

    //value.toUpperCase()

    return value.toFixed(2)
}
```

Note that for type guard `x is T`, TypeScript always assumes that if the type guard function returns `true`, `x` surely has type `T`. We
could write `isString()` incorrectly:

```
function isString(x: unknown): x is string {
    return typeof x === 'number' 
}
```

And TypeScript would not give any error inside of `formatValue()`

During runtime, we would get an error. If we call `formatValue(10)`, the code would execute like this:

```js
function formatValue(value: number | string): string {
    // isString(10) returns `true`, because `typeof 10 === 'number'`
    if (isString(value)) {
        // We attempt to call (10).toUpperCase(). Since
        // Since object Number(10) has no `toUpperCase` property,
        // (10).toUpperCase is `undefined`. Since we try to call it
        // as a function, we get TypeError from JS, during runtime
        return value.toUpperCase()
    }

    return value.toFixed(2)
}
```

So it's our responsibility to write type predicates that actually return `true` only when `x` has type `T`

### `as const` and `readonly T[]`

Imagine that we need to check if `value: unknown` is one of strings 'a', 'b' or 'c' at runtime, and also let TypeScript infer that `value` has type `'a' | 'b' | 'c'` if that's the case

Runtime check can be done using an array:

```
const letters = ['a', 'b', 'c']

if (letters.includes(value)) {
   // ...
}
```

But how do we tell TS that `value` has type `'a' | 'b' | 'c'` inside if?

We could use this function:

```js
function isIn<T>(values: T[], x: any): x is T {
    return values.includes(x)
}
```

But the inference doesn't work:

```js
// TS things that T=string here, so `isIn()` returns `x is string`
if (isIn(letters, value)) {
   // TS known that `value` has type `string` here, but we
   // need a narrower type - 'a' | 'b' | 'c'
}
```

The root of the problem is that `const letters` above has type `string[]`. If we use `as const`, TS would say that `letters has narrower type -` ['a', 'b', 'c']`:

```js
// letters is of type readonly ['a', 'b', 'c'] here
const letters = ['a', 'b', 'c'] as const
```

See [What does the "as const" mean in TypeScript and what is its use case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66993264/what-does-the-as-const-mean-in-typescript-and-what-is-its-use-case) for details

If we try to pass readonly array to `isIn()`, we get an error:

```js
if (isIn(letters, value)) {
    //   ^ The type 'readonly ["a", "b", "c"]' is 'readonly'
    //     and cannot be assigned to the mutable type 'unknown[]'
}
```

In theory, isIn() could mutate `values` inside, and TS tries to prevent mutation of values with `readonly` types. We say that
the parameter of isIn() has `readonly` type, declaring intent the it does not modify it's parameter:

```js
function isIn<T>(values: readonly T[], x: any): x is T {
    return values.includes(x);
}
```

Finally, type inference works:

```js
// Since `letters` has type `['a', 'b', 'c']` here,
// TS infers `T` in `T[]` to be `'a' | 'b' | 'c'`
if (isIn(letters, value)) {
    // So isIn() returns `x is 'a' | 'b' | 'c'`, and
    // TS says that `value` has type `'a' | 'b' | 'c'` here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  Could perhaps be simplified to

`function isIn<T>(values: readonly T[], x: T): x is T { return values.includes(x) }`

Comment: @wprl Yes, I think these are equivalent

Comment: This appears to only work with `x: any` parameter in `isIn` but not when `x: string`

Comment: @brettinternet If I understood you correctly, this is because `Array<T>.includes()` has type `T` for its parameter, so other types are not allowed to pass. If you want to restrict your `x` type to some type `U`, you can modify this function slightly: `function isIn<T, U>(values: readonly T[], x: U): x is T { return values.includes(x as any) }`. But I'm not sure why would you need that, since if x is of some other type, you will know it since the function will return `false`

Comment: can you explain why `values` should be `readonly T[]` but not just `T[]`, what does `x is T` mean and why the function should be it?

Comment: @Ooker I edited the answer to give some hints how it works

Answer (score 5):

Here's a solution that works well for strings & string literals using [TypeScript 4.1 Template Literal Types](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-1/#template-literal-types) that doesn't break anything else, and also narrows the type for convenience when used in conditions:

```js
declare global {
    interface ReadonlyArray<T> {
        includes<S, R extends `${Extract<S, string>}`>(
            this: ReadonlyArray<R>,
            searchElement: S,
            fromIndex?: number
        ): searchElement is R & S;
    }
}
```

Originally posted by noppa in [a TypeScript github issue related to this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26255#issuecomment-736971438).

Answer (score 2):

I strongly recommend including [ts-reset](https://github.com/total-typescript/ts-reset) library into you projects, which will improve TypeScript's built-in typings.

Comment: how does it implement the improvement?

Comment: It makes the type wider https://github.com/total-typescript/ts-reset/blob/main/src/entrypoints/array-includes.d.ts

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a curried version of `Array.prototype.includes` which works with tuples:

```js
const PROPS = ['a', 'b', 'c'] as const;

const withTuple = <
    List extends string[]
>(list: readonly [...List]) =>
    (prop: string): prop is List[number] =>
        list.includes(prop)

const includes = withTuple(PROPS);

const result = includes('d')

declare let str: string

if (includes(str)) {
    str // "a" | "b" | "c"
}
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/w1ArGw)

Higher order function with `list` argument created for inference.

You can also check my [article](https://catchts.com/useful-patterns#includes)

Answer (score -4):

using lodash

```
const CAPITAL_LETTERS = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'Z'] as const;
_.includes(CAPITAL_LETTERS, 'A');
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) will help people understand the reasons for your code suggestion.