# Typescript string enum inverse mapping

Tags: typescript, enums

I have a string enum defined as follows:

```js
export enum UserRole {
  SHOP_DESIGNER = 'DG_PF00-CorpID-Designa_Shop-Designers',
  SHOP_EMPLOYEE = 'DG_PF00-CorpID-Designa_Shop-Employees',
  LOGISTICS_TEAM = 'DG_PF00-CorpID-Designa_Logistics',
}
```

I want to create a **type-safe** mapping from a an enum string value to its enum type:

```js
const USER_ROLE_NAMES<string, UserRole> = ....
```

So I can parse an arbitrary value by querying the map:

```js
let role: UserRole

// role = SHOP_DESIGNER 
role = USER_ROLE_NAMES.get('DG_PF00-CorpID-Designa_Shop-Designers')

// role = SHOP_DESIGNER 
role = USER_ROLE_NAMES.get('DG_PF00-CorpID-Designa_Shop-Employees')

// role = SHOP_DESIGNER 
role = USER_ROLE_NAMES.get('DG_PF00-CorpID-Designa_Logistics')

// role = undefined
role = USER_ROLE_NAMES.get('some arbitrary string value which is not an enum value')
```

I already tried the following:

```js
export const USER_ROLE_NAMES = new Map(Object.entries(UserRole).map(([key, value]: [string, UserRole]) => [value, key]));
```

but then the type of `USER_ROLE_NAMES` is `Map<UserRole, string>` and the map cannot be queried with a string.

If I invert the mapping

```
export const USER_ROLE_NAMES = new Map(Object.entries(UserRole).map(([key, value]: [string, UserRole]) => [key, value]));
```

then the type is correct, but the mapping is wrong (`'DESIGNA_USER' => 'DG_PF00-CorpID-Designa_Users',...` instead of `'DG_PF00-CorpID-Designa_Users' => 'DESIGNA_USER',...`

Comment: Hmm, the point of enums is that the values are meant to be *opaque*;  `UserRole` is strictly narrower than the union of the string literal values.  It is considered a type error to use the string literal `"DG_PF00-CorpID-Designa_Shop-Designers"` where `UserRole.SHOP_DESIGNER` is expected.  Trying to get the compiler to do otherwise would be "type unsafe" according to the language. So when you say you want a **type safe** reverse mapping it sort of sounds like you want the opposite? Maybe we're just using different terms.

Comment: Anyway when people want to peer into enum values it's often a sign that enums are not what they really want.  If you replace the enum with a const object then the particular problem you're talking about goes away, [see this](https://tsplay.dev/Na12BN).  Of course there are other problems: `Map<K, V>.get(k)` returns `V | undefined` regardless of what `k` is; the data structure has no notion of "definitely present" keys; and you can't `get()` an arbitrary string key either unless you make `K` a `string`.  What do you want to do about those two issues? Are they relevant to the question?

Comment: Wait a minute I just re-read the question and it looks like you don't want a reverse *mapping* at all; you just want to downcast strings to their equivalent enum values.  So you want https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43804805/check-if-value-exists-in-enum-in-typescript/43805090 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59376564/check-to-see-if-string-exists-in-enum etc maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At runtime, the value of `UserRole.SHOP_DESIGNER` is actually `'DG_PF00-CorpID-Designa_Shop-Designers'`, not `'SHOP_DESIGNER'`. So the mapping you are asking for would look like this (at runtime):

```
const theMapping ={
  'DG_PF00-CorpID-Designa_Shop-Designers': 'DG_PF00-CorpID-Designa_Shop-Designers',
  ...
}
```

If you want this "enum value" -> "enum member" mapping, you can construct it like this: [TypeScript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6&noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwKoGdhQEoQA2wcA3gFBxwDKAEgPIAKA+gCICi1AkgOIBy7PHAC8cAOSsezRgDEADHIC0AYWhgurRa2BYAlgHNEAQ2bUAFhDBadBxLixiANJRoMW7ALKMAMvQCa7Owi4pLS8kqqUOqa2nqGJuaWiuyoYIQQAJ7AOk4uvjxc1AAqXMrUzEXsAIIewRJSsgoqahrWccbM3hD6ulgwugDGDs4AvuTkAxCIfXCoRmBguoj6AFxwHvMAPH1QS-qOmDj4RMAAfMF2AO7r8wAU9ABGAFbAAzAAdABuRoTIOrfYXAEYgASneczAtxcVFuqGAqAeuAAaj8-iCROcANoAAwAJKQ4QjkajgCNsQdCYioCjfsAALpwIxYOCTaYwcggkHjYjwKAnACMwQhi2W730wBgt3qYSakWibVsCQsVlitnsYi5PLgfOIACYhfMRfoxRKpchEABrRAQS6IDXkIA)

```
export enum UserRole {
  SHOP_DESIGNER = 'DG_PF00-CorpID-Designa_Shop-Designers',
  SHOP_EMPLOYEE = 'DG_PF00-CorpID-Designa_Shop-Employees',
  LOGISTICS_TEAM = 'DG_PF00-CorpID-Designa_Logistics',
}

const mapping: Map<string, UserRole> = new Map(Object.values(UserRole).map(
    (memberValue) => [`${memberValue}`, memberValue] as const
))

let role1 = mapping.get('DG_PF00-CorpID-Designa_Shop-Designers')
let role2 = mapping.get('unknown')
```

Comment: that's exactly what I was looking for