# How to solve typescript being too restrictive on Array.includes()

Tags: typescript

I should be allowed to pass anything into `Array.includes` to check if it's in the array, but typescript doesn't want me to pass in something that isn't the right type. For instance:

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?&install-plugin=playground-clippy#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgTgVwJbCgXigIgIZjAGwkygB8sB7ObAOwHMiBuAKFElnPIBN1ZEVSsYcsGzBymZkwDG5agGdUAMz7A5ALl7JgAbQC6PbTjyFMAGgpU6RXZMUJqU4EllQkc+FoAUwABZI6GjAcnACUUADeTFBQcBDACHDUUMpacgB0-lL4CJwQct5+dCHMAL5MQA)

```
type Fruit = "apple" | "orange";
type Food = Fruit | "potato";

const fruits: Fruit[] = ["apple", "orange"];

function isFruit(thing: Food) {
  return fruits.includes(thing); // ts error: "potato" is not assignable to type 'Fruit'.
}
```

What is a clean way to fix this code with minimal impact on readability?

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26255 Assert that it's `unknown[]` instead IMO

Comment: @CertainPerformance That's not really the _best_ approach though

Comment: @Dai It's arguably a TS bug I think. There are other methods but I don't think there's a universal clean way to get around the `.includes` typing. `unknown[]` works, do you have a better idea? `if ((fruits as unknown[]).includes`

Comment: It's not a TS bug. By coding fruits: Fruit[]. You are saying you are 100% sure that fruits only contains fruit. Therefore the includes will only work for fruit.
You should only search for fruit inside of a fruit array and nothing else

Comment: The cleanest solution would be to simply declare `fruits` as `Food[]` instead of `Fruit[]`, but if you absolutely need to keep it as a `Fruit[]`, then could you make an assertion in your method:`if ((fruits as Food[]).includes(thing)) console.log("yes!");`

Comment: Back in the days I used something like this. I dont know if its even a solution or not but it did work out for me: `(fruits.includes(food as Fruit)) console.log("yes!");`

Comment: @Searnd @erfan yes, but we should avoid TypeScript type-assertions (`as`) as much as possible because there's zero runtime safety when you do that. At least write type-guard functions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does the argument for Array.prototype.includes(searchElement) need the same type as array elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53033854/why-does-the-argument-for-array-prototype-includessearchelement-need-the-same)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up doing this (seems no drawback):

```
function isFruit(thing: Food) {
  return (fruits as Food[]).includes(thing);
}
```

Comment: There is a drawback: `as` in TypeScript is in most cases a code smell. In my experience, it very frequently hides bugs. So even if the code is 100% right, this practice makes "right code look wrong" which is not good.

Answer (score 10):

First, please read this QA from TypeScript 3.x days where someone was asking essentially the same question as yourself: [TypeScript const assertions: how to use Array.prototype.includes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56565528/typescript-const-assertions-how-to-use-array-prototype-includes)

Now, in your case, as an alternative to @CertainPerformance's suggestion of `unknown[]` (which loses type information), you can legally widen `fruits` to `readonly string[]` (without using `as`), which is compatible with `Fruit` and `Food`:

```
type Fruit = "apple" | "orange";
type Food = Fruit | "potato" | "egg";

const fruits: readonly Fruit[] = ["apple", "orange"];

function isFruit(food: Food): food is Fruit {

  const fruitsAsStrings: readonly string[] = fruits;
  return fruitsAsStrings.includes(food);
}
```

---

An alternative, (theoretically more "correct") approach is to add a *variant* `includes` member to the `ReadonlyArray<T>` interface ([as suggested in the linked QA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56745484/159145)) which allows `U` to be a supertype of `T` instead of the other way around.

```
interface ReadonlyArray<T> {
  includes<U>(x: U & ((T & U) extends never ? never : unknown)): boolean;
}

type Fruit = "apple" | "orange";
type Food = Fruit | "potato" | "egg";

const fruits: readonly Fruit[] = ["apple", "orange"];

function isFruit(food: Food): food is Fruit {

  return fruits.includes(food);
}
```

---

Having said all of that... if you intend to use a collection-type as a value/type set-membership test, you should use a JavaScript `Set<T>` (or use `object` keys) instead of an `Array`: not only because of performance reasons (as both `Set<T>.has()` and `object` key lookup are `O(1)` but `Array.includes()` is `O(n)` - and also because TypeScript works better with `keyof` types.

...implementing that is an exercise for the reader.

Comment: This is what I had to do to make this work for me (TypeScript 4.8): add declare global and change the variable type slightly: `declare global { interface ReadonlyArray<T> { includes<U>(searchElement: (T & U) extends never ? never : U, fromIndex?: number): boolean } }`

Answer (score 0):

The solution you wound up with (type-cast) seems fine to me.

The issue you ran into is not unique to TypeScript. If we look at Java's [`List.contains` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains-java.lang.Object-) we see that even though you may have a List of strings, the `contains` method accepts any argument type (Object). TypeScript has chosen a more restrictive approach, limiting `includes` to only those types that are in the array.

In my opinion, Java's choice is too liberal, and TypeScript's choice is too restrictive. But these are the easiest solutions to the problem. After all, if you choose something in between, you will have to somehow be able to show that the type you pass to `includes` is related to the type in the array.

I chose to take on that challenge and have sane defaults for these kinds of methods in the [`Rimbu` immutable collections library](https://github.com/rimbu-org/rimbu):

```
import { HashSet } from "@rimbu/core";

type Fruit = "apple" | "orange";
type Food = Fruit | "potato";
type NonFruit = "car" | "house";

const fruits = HashSet.of<Fruit>("apple", "orange");

function isFruit(thing: Food) {
  // return fruits.has(thing);           // Error: "potato" not assignable to "Fruit"
  // return fruits.has(3);               // Error: 3 not assignable to "Fruit"
  // return fruits.has<NonFruit>("car"); // Error: "car" not assignable to Fruit
  return fruits.has<Food>(thing);        // Correct way
}
```

In the example you see that simply saying `fruits.has(thing)` results in a compiler error. After all, the type `Food` is not a subset of `Fruit`, so it may be a mistake. However, if you tell the method that this is intentional by supplying the `Food` type parameter, everything is fine.

Now, why doesn't `fruit.has<NonFruit>("car")` work? Well, the `has` method has a restriction that the collection type and the argument should be in some way "related" (to be specific, either one has to extend the other). This is not the case for types `Fruit` and `NonFruit`. So even supplying the type will still result in a compiler error. If you are really certain that you want this, you can of course always supply `any` as parameter.

While this approach is still not perfect, I think it covers 95% of the use cases of such methods. Therefore you will find this approach all over the place in Rimbu collections.

Here is a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-kare-q7pzl?file=/src/index.ts) where you can play with this example.

Comment: I think you haven't read my comment well, I put in a link to Java's List.contains method as a counter example of a way that I believe is too liberal. I put in the other example of TypeScript being too restrictive. And I put in an example of how you create something in between in TypeScript. I don't really understand your remark about object value equality though. Maybe you can give an example?

Comment: Correct, I apologize - I didn't read your answer in full.

Answer (score -1):

Today I came across that case.

```
const validNumbers: TValidNumber[] = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
```

You will likely face the problem that the "includes" method only accepts the "TValidNumber" type as a parameter, and you are likely passing a "string" to it. I couldn't find an answer in the 20 minutes I spent researching this, so after trying, I found that you can tell or assign the type to "validNumbers" to be both an Array of TValidNumber and an Array of "string" in the following way:

```
const validNumbers: TValidNumber[] & string[] = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
```

From hating TypeScript to loving it with great force in an instant hehehe, just as it has helped me, I hope it helps a lot of people.

Comment: If you do this, there won't be any guard against putting "yellow" inside validNumbers when you declare it.

Comment: It was honestly demoralizing to receive a negative vote when I was only trying to help.
I just tried the following code and see that I am right

`type TValidNumber = 'one' | 'two' | 'three';

const validNumbers: TValidNumber[] & string[] = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'];
`
Over 'four' I have: BugFinder: Type '"four"' is not assignable to type '"one" | "two" | "three"'.

Comment: I tested myself, you're right, sorry, although I still don't understand why. I tried to remove my downvote, stackoverflow told me I'll be allowed to do so once you make any edit to your answer.