# How to derive a runtime value from a conditional type?

Tags: typescript

I'm writing a typed wrapper around a protocol used between a server and my client. This protocol can return a single response or multiple responses. Each of the responses has a value. I could just collect the results and return them as an array to the application. However, that would mean I have to do additional checks before I can use single values.

The vast majority of the responses is single-valued, so I'd like to avoid having this check and have hence defined a conditional return type, based on an enum which holds the APIs names, that may return more than a single value. Still, also these APIs can just come back with a single value, but in this case it's ok for me to return an array with just this single result.

Now I need to know if I should return a single value or an array from my function at runtime. Check this code:

```
enum APIs {
    api1 = "API1",
    api2 = "API2",
    api3 = "API3",
}

type MultiResult =
    typeof APIs.api1
    | typeof APIs.api2
    ;

interface IResultMapper {
    [APIs.api1]: { result: string[] };
    [APIs.api2]: { values: string };
    [APIs.api3]: { name: string };
}

const values: string[] = [];
function record(value: string): void {
    values.push(value);
}

type Result<T extends keyof IResultMapper> = T extends MultiResult ? string[] : string;

function done<T extends keyof IResultMapper>(api: T, value: string): Result<T> {
    if (isMultiResult) {
        values.push(value);
        return values;
    }

    return value;
}

console.log(done<APIs.api1>("test"));
```

Also available in the [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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).

Imagine my connection receives data responses and I call function `record` for each, and a final response with the last value, for which I call function `done`. In reality this is all done with promises, but for this question I simplified that a lot. The point is that there might be no data responses sometimes, even for APIs that are marked as returning multiple data records. But all requests return at least a final response.

The `done` function now needs to decide if it has to return an array or a single value. For that I need a flag at runtime that I can check, as all type info is erased (see the `if (multiResult)` part in the code.

So, how can I derive a runtime value from the `Result` type? Side note: the `APIs` enum , the `IResultMapper` interface and the `MultiResult` type are auto generated and can grow really large (hundreds of entries).

Comment: What is the question here? You haven't written `isMultiResult` yet, do you ask how it should be implemented so that `return values` does not throw an error?

Comment: Yes, how can I set the variable `isMultiResult` based on the used API or more generally: how to derive a fixed value from a type that I can use at runtime.

Comment: Well have you check io-ts library? It will probably do what you want to do with wrappers.

Comment: The only way this could work is to generate a *value* from which the  `MultiResult` type can be derived, and then use the value to check inside `done()`. I could write up an example, but I'm very confused about what `IResultMapper` is supposed to be doing in your example code. You're not really using it in the example, except for referring to `keyof IResultMapper` which is just `APIs`.  Could you [edit] to clarify what's happening with that? Can we just remove it? (`record()` too, for that matter) If you do this and want me to take another look, please mention @jcalz in a comment to notify me.

Comment: Like, [this code](https://tsplay.dev/NB5xzw) is how I would do what I think you're asking, but there's no reference to `IResultMapper` or `record()` in it. Does that make sense? Let me know how to proceed (@jcalz to notify me)

Comment: That makes a lot of sense @jcalz. Of course the way should be to define a value and get a conditional type from that instead of the other way around. Please post your solution as answer.

Comment: I'll do so when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noted, the static type system is [erased](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/basic-types.html#erased-types) when TypeScript is compiled into JavaScript, so your `MultiResult` type will not exist at runtime, and there's nothing from which you can implement `isMultiResult()`.

Instead, you should implement the `isMultiResult()` function (so it will exist as a value at runtime) and then derive the `MultiResult` type from it using [the `typeof` type operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html) to get access to types of your values.  Actually it's even easier to create some value and use its value to both implement `isMultiResult` and derive `MultiResult`:

```
const multiResult = [APIs.api1, APIs.api2] as const;
// const multiResult: readonly [APIs.api1, APIs.api2]
```

The value `multiResult` is an array holding the `APIs` elements that you want to be part of `MultiResult`.  By using a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) we are asking the compiler to treat `multiResult` as a [`readonly` tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#readonly-tuples) of [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types), so it knows exactly which values are in there (and the exact order and length of the array also, but we don't actually care about that information).

You can recover `MultiResult` like this:

```
type MultiResult = typeof multiResult[number];
// type MultiResult = APIs.api1 | APIs.api2
```

which is using [indexed access](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) to get the type of the properties at numeric keys of `multiResult` (that is, the array element types), and thus the [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) you want.

Now we can implement `isMultiResult` by looking up the relevant `APIs` value in the `multiResult` array:

```
function isMultiResult(api: APIs) {
    const m: readonly APIs[] = multiResult;
    return m.includes(api);
}
```

(Conceptually you would just return `multiResult.includes(api)` but you have to work around a typing restriction; see [TypeScript const assertions: how to use Array.prototype.includes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56565528/2887218) and/or [Why does the argument for Array.prototype.includes(searchElement) need the same type as array elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53033854/2887218) for more information.)

And now your `done()` implementation looks like:

```
type Result<K extends APIs> = K extends MultiResult ? string[] : string;
const values: string[] = [];
function done<K extends APIs>(api: K, value: string): Result<K> {
    if (isMultiResult(api)) {
        values.push(value);
        return values as Result<K>;
    }
    return value as Result<K>;
}
```

And that works!

```
const arr = done(APIs.api1, "test");
console.log(arr.join(",")) // "test"
const arr2 = done(APIs.api2, "also");
console.log(arr2.join(",")) // "test,also"
const str = done(APIs.api3, "okay");
console.log(str.toUpperCase()) // "OKAY"
```

Looks good!

(This is outside of the scope of the question, but if you wonder why I needed to [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) that the return values are the right type, i.e., `as Result<K>`: Since `Result<K>` is a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) and `K` is a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter, the compiler cannot verify when a value is or is not assignable to `Result<K>`, so it just issues an error unless you use a type assertion.  This is a current TypeScript design limitation with various open feature requests asking for improvements. The most relevant one is probably [microsoft/TypeScript#33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912), if you want to learn more.)

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAggCgSQM5QN4CgpagQwA4CWAjFALxQBE8CRFANJtvgQExmXUv2NbMDM7Koj7cAvunQB6SVAAuACwIolUAO7ycsqAE8A9mCgBzUMABOm4FAIgks4DgAmUXQDMd+01ACyYADayCACVgJD8tWW08YAkAY10bLQgwoJCw9gBtaiQAOmYiOlhEHOYWAF1cFDiEgG4pGSrbKCT-FND-AC4oU3sHeN9tKEyi3MJ8wuQR1lKJFzAQGID4qyQfFuC22QAKZk6sgEo0HigGxM7uxz6BrPTy8maA9bDa7C7gWTBTECbs6xjfMAcIW2hD2tXEESi3mSj387AhwFcTWhqX86XAEAARmZSrVpHJIpZVg8UVpyFlJiQAD7jYqEFgSeFQGGyAA8AGkoMAAB52EAOFBZAB87A53N5-KhaxJUAA-FBbKZrIYblBOgqlbVYvFGgA3HD-EJq2SKkDK26DHHoWbzRZfXogYDszk80ASoXAgidNkFPUGo0mwx7TrM9nCjAvAhuTZKImtMIevYHcMvbC+sAhbJ4MBIeSbNPAUFHF7dd6fKD5lA4FAhtmC57YcTFt4fL75ipMkmhsFahK4Uyecj24Cbcl5AoUOy2CiFhq6XzAbK+XSGbb97IAK101k29GnBzxE5Csgo6BOfdMbEH8WHo7p4-1SF009qs-ni+Xq4vG63IB3dD3UAHpOsh0A+T6ntqWgKuwQ4jsM-DjroADWODaM+EE2HOC5LiuCrZLIugAKp4FEpgAMJVsOiaATIFAAPJsjAACaJ7oEAA)