# Filter array with type inference

Tags: typescript, type-inference, conditional-types

I'm trying to properly infer function result type. Example below:

```
enum UserType {
  ADMIN,
  VIEWER,
  PUBLISHER,
}

interface User {
  name: string;
  type: UserType;
}

const userTypes = [UserType.PUBLISHER, UserType.VIEWER];

const users = [
  { name: 'Paul', type: UserType.ADMIN },
  { name: 'Steve', type: UserType.VIEWER },
  { name: 'Marry', type: UserType.PUBLISHER },
];

const getUsersByTypes = (users: User[], types: UserType[]) => {
  return users.filter(user => types.includes(user.type));
};

const filteredUsers = getUsersByTypes(users, userTypes);
```

Inferred type of `filteredUsers` variable is `User[]`. I wish it to be an array of Users where property `type` should be an union of `userTypes` variable, so in this case role should be type of `UserType.PUBLISHER | UserType.VIEWER`. Can't figure out how to achive that.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WvqpQm) meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: The result is exactly what I need. I know concepts about generic types, but couldn't turn it into solution in this case. I will analyze it step by step. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you care about a specific subtype of `User` where the `type` property has been narrowed from `UserType`, it will be easiest to modify `User` to be [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the `type` property, while still having it [default](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) to the original version:

```
interface User<T extends UserType = UserType> {
  name: string;
  type: T;
}
```

Also, if you want `getUsersByTypes` to return `User<T>[]` for some narrower `T`, then you really need to make sure that the `types` array passed to it has a type narrower than `UserType[]`:

```
const userTypes = [UserType.PUBLISHER, UserType.VIEWER];
// const userTypes: UserType[] //
```

That means your `userTypes` variable probably needs to be curated a little more closely, say by using a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) to ask for a more specific type:

```
const userTypes = [UserType.PUBLISHER, UserType.VIEWER] as const;
// const userTypes: readonly [UserType.PUBLISHER, UserType.VIEWER]
```

---

Okay, now we're finally in a place to proceed.  You're going to want to make `getUsersByTypes` generic in the type `T` corresponding to the elements of the `types` argument, and you're going to want to return a `User<T>[]`, like this:

```
declare const getUsersByTypes: <T extends UserType>(
  users: readonly User[], types: readonly T[]
) => User<T>[]
```

Note that I used [a readonly array type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#the-readonlyarray-type) for both parameters; that's because `readonly X[]` is *wider* than `X[]` (you can assign the latter to the former but not vice versa) and since `const` assertions result in `readonly` arrays, it's best to widen to `readonly` array parameters (unless you want to modify the input arrays, which you don't).

That will now work as desired from the caller's side:

```
const filteredUsers = getUsersByTypes(users, userTypes);
// const filteredUsers: User<UserType.VIEWER | UserType.PUBLISHER>[]
```

---

As for the implementation, it's a bit of a hassle to try to get the compiler to verify it as type safe.

You essentially need to mark the filter callback as a [custom type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates), since the compiler can't infer that.  And otherwise `filter()` wouldn't return a narrower type than the input.

And you also need to widen the `types` array from `readonly T[]` to `readonly UserType[]` when calling `includes()` on it because TS doesn't like to let you pass a wider input to `includes()`, even though it's perfectly safe to do so.  See [TypeScript const assertions: how to use Array.prototype.includes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56565528/2887218) .

But once you do both of those the compiler is happy:

```
const getUsersByTypes = <T extends UserType>(
  users: readonly User[], types: readonly T[]
) => {
  return users.filter((user): user is User<T> => 
    (types as readonly UserType[]).includes(user.type)
  );
};
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAqgzsATgFQJ4AdhQN4CgpQCCAIgLICSAcgDT5QBq5AogOpMBKtBACjAEIAZcgGUAEh1oBfXLgCWIAC5IAZgEMAxlnhIAPMijAAHkpAATOLAQoMWALyWkaTAD4cdEKojAAXFDgLEeQBzAG46BRtfZDDpGXUAexB-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)